# how to Insert multivalues itmes from checkedlistbox into single field access

Tags: vb.net

I have a CheckedListBox which designates the file documents to be provided I want the checked boxes to be stored in a single field named pieces_fourni in my access table and the unchecked boxes to be stored in another single field named pieces_manquant I have tried several times without success, Can anybody help me here is the code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 
cn.Open()
 
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
Dim x, z As Integer
 
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tab_asso(id_dossier,denomination,date_recep,nom_prenom,adresse,wilaya,code_wilaya,region,pieces_fourni,pieces_manquant) values('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & CheckedListBox1.Items(x).ToString & ",""',""' , '" & CheckedListBox1.Items(z).ToString & "' ", cn)
 
        cmd.Connection = cn
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
        CheckedListBox1.DataSource = dt
        CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "dossier_ass"
        CheckedListBox1.ValueMember = "DESIGNATIONS"
        CheckedListBox1.Text = ""
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
 
        For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1
 
 
            If CheckedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) = True Then
                i = x
            Else
                i = z
            End If
 
        Next
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 
        MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfuly")
 
        cn.Close()
 
    End Sub

`type here`
```

Comment: The normal way to do it would be to have another table with columns such as "id_dossier", "checkboxName", and "state". There are many articles available on how to *normalize* your database, for example [this one](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/database_normalization_basics.html).

Comment: Then, you really should use SQL parameters to pass data to the database: it avoids problems such as queries breaking if there is an apostrophe in the data, and helps prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. One option is to use an integer value of some type and treat each bit in the number as a Boolean value. That way, you save a single value to the database but you have multiple values in your application. The data type would depend on how many values you need, e.g. `int` can handle up to 32 and `bigint` can handle up to 64 in a SQL Server database. You would need application code to combine and separate the values. This option is efficient with regards to storage but means you can't easily see what's what in the database itself.